# Acceleration of output images

Tags: java, awt

Hello) There was a question whether it is possible to speed up the code as that which is below:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        int w = 20;
        int h = 20;
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.dispose();
        int MapWidth = image.getWidth(this);
        int MapHeight = image.getHeight(this);

        for (int s = MapWidth - MapWidth; s < MapWidth * 10; s++) {
            for (int i = MapHeight - MapHeight; i < MapHeight * 10; i++) {
                g.drawImage(image, s, i, (int) w, (int) h, this);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                frame.add(new Game());

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

He draws pictures for so long. How can it speed up? Help please)

And one program can not be closed until the drawn image.
It is necessary to accelerate their drawing

Comment: Do you realize : "MapWidth - MapWidth" will be always zero :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slow, because in your

```
    for (int s = 0; s < MapWidth * 10; s++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight * 10; i++) {
            g.drawImage(image, s, i, (int) w, (int) h, this);
        }
    }
```

For 400*400 MapWidth, MapHeight you are painting 4000*4000 objects, so you paint 16 000 000 objects, it should be slow.

If you replace it with this, it will be fast as hell :) :

```
    for (int s = 0; s < MapWidth * 10; s += w) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight * 10; i += h) {
            g.drawImage(image, s, i, (int) w, (int) h, this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try below code

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        int w = 20;
        int h = 20;
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.dispose();
        int MapWidth = image.getWidth(this);
        int MapHeight = image.getHeight(this);

        for (int s = MapWidth - MapWidth; s < MapWidth * 10; s++) {
            for (int i = MapHeight - MapHeight; i < MapHeight * 10; i=i+10) {
                g.drawImage(image, s, i, (int) w, (int) h, this);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                frame.add(new Game());

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```